# Enable selected breakpoints after disabling all (visual studio c++ 2010)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to temporarily disable all active breakpoints and then renable only those breakpoints which were previously enabled. To give a quick example, suppose I have the following 5 breakpoints:

1,3,5 are enabled
2,4 are disabled

Now I disable all breakpoints and little later, I want to enable only 1,3,5.

If I choose "Disable all breakpoints" and then "enable all breakpoints", all of 1,2,3,4,5 breakpoints are enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

1. Export all breakpoints matching the current search criteria = in the `Breakpoints` window click on the icon with a blue diskette
2. Disable all breakpoints
3. Import breakpoints from a file = in the `Breakpoints` window click on the icon with a blue arrow

This will restore breakpoints with the enable/disable state as well.